# How to build parameters for System.cmd?

Tags: imagemagick, elixir

I want to use System.cmd run "convert" from ImageMagick, but I am having difficulty

```
System.cmd("convert", ["origin.jpg", "-fill", "black", "-pointsize", "12", "-gravity", "SouthWest", "-draw", "\"text +4,+4 'Test hello world!'\"", "output.jpg"])
```

The args `-draw` 's value is `\"text +4,+4 'Test hello world!'\"`, but ImageMagick requires `"text +4,+4 'Test hello world!'"` Do not need to escape double quotes.
How can I do it？

Comment: Try `[..., "text +4,+4 'Test hello world!'", ...]`. (No escaped outer double quotes.)

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the outer double quotes here with `System.cmd/3`. You need them when running the command from the shell because the argument contains spaces and without the outer double quotes the shell will split the whole thing on every space and end up passing the equivalent of `["text", "+4,+4", "Test hello world!"]`. The following should work:

```
System.cmd(..., [..., "text +4,+4 'Test hello world!'", ...])
```